# PgAdmin not displaying any result on specific table seeded through TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, pgadmin, nestjs-typeorm

I have 3 entities: user, role, status.

**ER diagram**:

[image]

**Tables creation and seeding (migrations) are done through TypeORM in NestJS.**

Both `role` and status `tables` are populated with defined columns and data as seen from the images below.

[image]

[image]

**Problem**:
`user` table is correctly populated with columns (as seen from the ER diagram, and also in PgAdmin columns are visible on the table in the sidebar), but when I do simple `SELECT * FROM user;`, I get some weird result:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had to prepend `public.` (default schema) to the `user` table in the query, like `SELECT * FROM public.user;`. This is a bit strange since I don't have to do this with `role` and `status` tables.